# Your binary is designed for iPad Pro. Upload iPad Pro screenshots for a better App Store experience warning

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

After submitting the app to app store for review, I got below alert in iTunes Connect. I don't see the option to upload iPad Pro screenshots in iTunes Connect.[image]

Please let me know what can be done here.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. I think it's a glitch, or a tease. I'll gladly add screenshots with the pro if they gave me one early on to test.

Comment: You might want to mark the updated answer as solved for other users to find the now working solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is an error at Apple's side. I have submitted my app with this error and Apple approved the app.

Answer (score 5):

> **Update:**

**iTunes Connect** now supports uploading **iPad Pro Screenshots**
[image: iTunes Connect (german)]
(german screenshot)

*As mentioned by @MikeKeskinov this may be only visible if the app is **not** already **ready for sale**. (thanks for commenting)*

Comment: Note: do not be confused - look for this tab in the app version which is in "Prepare for submission" state. If your app is in "Ready for sale" state, the "iPad Pro" tab may be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because there still isn't a option to upload screenshots for the iPad Pro. No doubt error on Apple's side.

Comment: Note: do not be confused - look for this tab in the app version which is in "Prepare for submission" state. If your app is in "Ready for sale" state, the "iPad Pro" tab may be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It's available now in xCode 7.1
Now you can launch your application in iPad Pro iOS simulator.
[xCode 7.1 simulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgpCS.png)